# C++ Windows - Get PIDs of process by executable file path

Tags: c++, winapi, pid

It's known and often asked how to get the full path to an executable from its PID. However, I need the opposite: I need to find the PID of the process from an absolute path to its executable.

Is there a simple way to do that, or should I fetch all PIDs and compare the executable path manually?

Why do I need that? I need to terminate junk instances of this process without killing other processes which have the same name as the process I should terminate.

Comment: Look at POSIX functions.

Comment: enumerate all processes, if name match - query path of process

Comment: Do you have the process id that you want to keep?

Comment: And how did you think to differ which pid to terminate and which not to in case you have the same process name but with a different pids?

Comment: To figure that out, I should use an absolute path to executable I ran which IS same and nothing also. If the name matches without matching the absolute path, then, it's a PID to keep.

Comment: @EylM, any PIDs I should keep - alien processes (ran out of my main project) with the same name. So, to find necessary processes to kill I should use full path rather just a name only to figure out PIDs to kill.

Comment: @Wohlstand what stylo was asking is how do you plan to differentiate between processes where the absolute EXE file has been executed multiple times? The absolute path will be the same of each of those processes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, so, I'll kill all of them, it's all that I need! This process is never using multiple times on the same machine as the launcher software a singleton application (it can't be launched multiple times at the same time). There are only zombies (a process that got stuck on an attempt to properly terminate it) can appear and they are should be killed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct API call to get the process ID of an absolute path.  As you surmised, you will have to enumerate all processes until you find the path you are interested in, then you will have its process ID.  Look at [`EnumProcesses()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses) or [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot) for that. See [Process Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-enumeration) on MSDN for examples.

Comment: Made!
It works!
So, the full working example code I made that solves my question: https://gist.github.com/Wohlstand/ce309fff0a70d94e1c31524bb16fad59